# In a LINQ select how can I select the FirstOrDefault of a list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have these objects:

```
public interface IJapaneseDictionaryEntry
{
    int Sequence { get; }
    IEnumerable<IKanji> Kanjis { get; }
    IEnumerable<IReading> Readings { get; }
    IEnumerable<ISense> Senses { get; }
}

public interface IKanji
{
    string Text { get; }
    IEnumerable<KanjiInformation> Informations { get; }
    IEnumerable<Priority> Priorities { get; }
}
```

and a LINQ query:

```
var d = entries.SelectMany(x => x.Kanjis)
   .Where(x => x.Priorities.Any(pri => pri.Code.StartsWith("nf")))
   .Select(x => new { x.Text, x.Priorities });
```

What I would like to do is select the first entry so I did this:

```
var d = entries.SelectMany(x => x.Kanjis)
               .Where(x => x.Priorities.Any(pri => pri.Code.StartsWith("nf")))
               .Select(x => new { x.Text, x.Priorities.StartsWith("nf").FirstOrDefault().Code });
```

But it's giving me an error for this:

```
.Select(x => new { x.Text, x.Priorities.StartsWith("nf").FirstOrDefault().Code });
```

saying:

> ApplyFrequency.cs(56,56): Error CS1061: 'IEnumerable' does
>   not contain a definition for 'StartsWith' and no extension method
>   'StartsWith' accepting a first argument of type
>   'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (Download)

Can anyone give me advice on what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Should `StartsWith("nf").FirstOrDefault()` instead be `FirstOrDefault(z => z.StartsWith("nf"))`?

Comment: Why `SelectMany(x => x.Kanjis)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just place the `StartsWith` inside the `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var d = entries.SelectMany(x => x.Kanjis)
               .Where(x => x.Priorities.Any(pri => pri.Code.StartsWith("nf")))
               .Select(x => new { 
                   x.Text,                     
                   x.Priorities.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Code.StartsWith("nf"))?.Code 
               });
```

You can also go without the `?.` operator as you filter out only those that do have a priority matching the condition.

Another way of writing this would be:

```
var d = entries.SelectMany(x => x.Kanjis.Select(x => new { 
                   x.Text,                     
                   x.Priorities.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Code.StartsWith("nf"))?.Code 
               }).Where(x => x.Code != null);
```

Comment: Yup this looks better